# VMware Winx64 key

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, 64-bit

Im using a legal copy of Windows x64 on a Dell machine. I Want to virtualize it and run it on another Dell using VMware

Prob: The VM wants a x64 bit key. The host is also running a legal copy of Win X64. How do I determine the key for x64 so I can enter it into VMware. Or, is there another workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Your key is stored in the Registry. Alot of guides from an initial google search seem to refer using http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/.

Use at your own risk.

From some light research newer versions of windows encrypt the keys. You might be able to find it unencrypted since your using windows xp.

A version of the key is also shown in the general tab under system in control panel, but this is probably not what you need.

**Your safest option is probably to contact Microsoft.**

Comment: You may need to "retire" the physical license in order to keep the licensing "legit," versus having two systems on the same license concurrently.

Comment: +1 for jellybean, it's a great tool

Answer (score 0):

Use the same key that you used for the Dell.